# Automatically get columns names in form: name_of_table.name_of_row

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to obtain data from several tables in database using join. Tables contains rows with equal names. Is it possible automatically get columns names in form: `name_of_table.name_of_column`?
For example instead of `Select using table1.column as t1col from...` write only `Select * from...`?

Comment: Try the INFORMATION_SCHEMA tables to retrieve metadata like that.  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-schema.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not possible. You have to explicitily ask for the fields by assigning aliases, this way: `... name_of_table.field1 as name_of_table_field1, name_of_table.field2 as name_of_table_field2 ...`

I researched this same question myself weeks ago and finally adopted this solution.